# Taking 4-5 second to visible view with big ArrayList data to RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have three RecyclerView in NestedScrollView, 2 RecyclerView having approx 100 items and third having approx 400 items. Then it takes 4-5 seconds to render the view after adding data to arraylist and notifiedDataSetChanged(). Every RecyclerView is in vertical. So if there any solution for this please explain

```
if(!itemsList.isEmpty()) {itemsList.clear();}
itemsList.addAll(itemData);
itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: move to index of arraylist means?

Comment: I understand the problem, after observation. Problem is having 400 items in RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. So how to handle this thing.

Comment: Pls edit your question with exact issue

Comment: Check edit question for exact issue.

Comment: well, it can be a lot of things but are you tried to load less items on recycler view already? Perhaps you can solve this with pagination

Comment: Sorry but as per requirements there is no pagination needed, because we can't move to last index without having data.

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview inside nested scrollview does complete layout at a single load rather than usual recyclerview behaviour, try to remove nested scrollview from layout, use recyclerview with different view types.